# How to undo an Eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, workspace

Is it possible to **undo** an Eclipse workspace without deleting the whole directory? By this I mean to keep the projects in the same directory but the directory should no longer be a workspace.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Eclipse option to do this but you can do a reasonable job by deleting various directories and files in the workspace:

- The `.metadata` directory holds most of the Eclipse data. Deleting this will stop Eclipse recognising the workspace.
- In each project deleting the `.project` file will stop Eclipse recognising the project as a project.
- You could also delete the `.classpath` file and any `.settings` directory in each project. Some types of project may have additional files that can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the projects as eclipse projects then just deleting the .metadata folder is enough (for some eclipse packages, one or more of the projects may also be eclipse generated and could be deleted, so any projects not recognized can be deleted). Now, eclipse needs to run with a workspace so when you start eclipse with a fresh workspace, you can import the projects from the old workspace folder but don't select the import option which gets the projects copied into the new workspace.

In this way, your new workspace will just have metadata for the workspace but the projects themselves will stay in the first directory.

(Strictly speaking, you don't need to delete anything from the old workspace directory. Instead, simply don't select it as a workspace when starting eclipse. However, deleting the .metadata folder would get rid of unnecessary data.)

Note that if you delete the .metadata folder and then later want to use the directory again, as an eclipse workspace, you can just select it when starting eclipse. However, in this case, the projects will not be automatically recognized as being in the workspace (even though they are in the directory), since that information was in the .metadata folder. To get them recognized again, as projects, you will need to import them, though you won't need to set the copy option in the import wizard.